# Error en ASP TextBox: El nombre 'txtFecha" no existe en el contexto actual

Tags: asp.net, asp

Tengo un control ASP TextBox con ID = "txtFecha" que captura una fecha de un control CalendarExtender. 
Cuando intento acceder al valor en codebehind del objeto txtFecha.Text el compilador me muestra el mensaje: El nombre 'txtFecha' no existe en el contexto actual.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFecha" runat="server" maxlength="10" ReadOnly = "false"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFecha" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Campo requerido" Text="*" ControlToValidate = "txtFecha"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" ID="rvFecha" Type="Date" ControlToValidate="txtFecha" MaximumValue='01/01/2100' MinimumValue="01/01/1900"
ErrorMessage="Fecha no valida" Display="Dynamic" />
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID = "Calender1" runat = "server" TargetControlID = "txtFecha"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

En codebehind

```
Session["Fecha"] = txtFecha.Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los controles en ASP.Net son agregados dinamicamente. Puedes realizar un casting del componente de la siguiente manera (Utilizando un contexto de ejemplo llamado "Formulario").

```
Session["Fecha"] = ((TextBox)Formulario.FindControl("txtFecha")).Text;
```

Si no tienes un Id para el contenedor puedes usar el PlaceHolder de la Pagina. En este caso "ContentPlaceHolder1":

```
ContentPlaceHolder Formulario =
(ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1")
```

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente ! Gracias !